# Can you have a keylistener in a java console application?

Tags: java, console-application, keylistener

Can you have a keylistener in a java console application without messing with JNI?  Will jcurses do this for me (I couldn't find it in my searching.)  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly. Jcurses will probably do the trick, but contains native code.

Comment: It means that jcurses contains native code and that you potentially have to compile jcurses yourself for every platform you intend to run your application on. AFAIK, jcurses binaries are only available for 32-bit versions of Windows and Linux.